# most efficient way to validate us zip code in Flex

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, apache-flex, zipcode

I have a Flex application that needs to be able to validate hundreds of zip codes fairly quickly. I also want to keep the memory space used by the app as small as possible.

Here are a few solutions my team has come up with. Any thoughts on them? Any other ideas?

Check each zip code via...

1. array of valid zip codes
2. array of invalid zip codes
3. soap call to a web service that validates zip codes
4. query a database table
5. a tree - 5 nodes high, nodes at the bottom would have boolean values of whether or not the zip is valid. The zip code of 12345 would go from the root to it's first child, to it's second... you get the point
6. validate first 3 numbers via array of valid USPS SCFs then the last two digits via array specific to that SCF.

Comment: If memory usage is the main concern; then I wouldn't load all your zip codes in memory and store them that way.  I'd ping a remote service which will return the UI each zip code in question and whether or not it validated successfully.  if speed is your main concern, then load up all the zip codes in memory and loop over them to validate.  Nonetheless; I voted to close as this is not a question that can be concretely answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you are looking for. Do you want to validate the format of the zip code (ie. that it is 5 digits long) or do you want to ensure the zip code is a valid US zip code. I will venture a guess that it is the latter. Take a look at the USPS address API (https://www.usps.com/business/webtools-address-information.htm?). I am willing to bet that will be perfect and less overhead then managing a DB or updating an array and managing all the xxxxx+4 zip codes.

Comment: We're already validating length. We need to make sure it's a valid US zip code.

Comment: Then using the USPS API i provided above will give you the most consistent and up to date info.